# separate mathematical expression in java

Tags: java

Would anyone be able to help me with separating this mathematical expression `125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4` in Java. I want to get the numbers form the expression, and I'm not sure how to use `split()` method over here.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the `split()` method. You need parsing tools for parsing problems (Chomsky 1956). Look up 'recursive descent expression parsing' or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use split with this regex `[*+]` :

```
String[] numbers = "125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4".split("[*+]");
```

**Outputs**

```
[125, 1, 4, 4, 82, 1, 10, 2, 59, 2, 4]
```

---

In case the mathematical expression contains spaces, you can remove them before and use split so you can use :

```
String[] numbers = "125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[*+]");
//---------------------------------------------^----------------------^
```

---

Note you can add another arithmetic operators like `[*+-/]`

---

Another solution from [eparvan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530707/separate-mathematical-expression-in-java/45530728#comment78021648_45530728):

In case you are not sure what the expression can contain you can use :

```
String[] numbers = "125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[^0-9]");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------^----^
```

---

**Edit**

> What if I want to get the "+" and "*" ?
>   **Input**: `125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4` **Output**: `***+**+*++`

In this case you can split with `\d+` like this :

```
String[] numbers = "125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4".replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("\\d+");
```

But i will prefert to go with Pattern it is more practice then split for example you can use :

```
String str = "125*1/4*4+82*1*10+2/59-2+4";
String regex = "[^\\d]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: It is better to use this `[^0-9]` regexp, just in case if the expression contains other arithmetic operations, like division, subtraction, etc.

Comment: thank you @eparvan check my edit i mentioned your name there

Comment: What if I want to get the "+" and "*" ?

Comment: what the output should look like @Ajifos ?

Comment: Input:125*1*4*4+82*1*10+2*59+2+4
Output:***+**+*++

Comment: `[*+-/]` will not work, since `-` has special meaning in a character class.

Comment: To get *all* the tokens, here is a cheat: `split("\\b")`. That will give you `[125, *, 1, *, 4, *, 4, +, 82, *, 1, *, 10, +, 2, *, 59, +, 2, +, 4]`. It's a cheat, because regex `\b` means *word-boundary*, and it so happens that digits are word-characters, so it'll split at beginning and end of any group of digits.

Comment: thank you yes this is correct @Andreas `split("\\b")` will work good in case the OP want all the tokens

Comment: @YCF_L `[*+-/]` means `*` and all characters from `+` to `/`, which are `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, and `/`. It *appears* to be working, because you don't have any `,` or `.`, but it is not working the way you intended.

Comment: ok @Andreas so should i to escape them like `[\\*\\+\\-/]` or what should i do exactly?

Comment: Just the `-`. Although `*` and `+` normally has special meaning in a regex, they don't inside a character class. `-` only has special meaning in a character class, but not outside in "normal" regex. You can also put the `-` either first or last, so any of these would work: `[*+\\-/]`, `[-+*/]`, or `[*/+-]`. The first is more explicit and less vulnerable to go bad if someone wants to add more characters later on, since people will recognize the escape, but are less familiar with the special way to do `-` first/last.